# Bootstrap: CardHeader with buttons on the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a Cardheader with Some text on the left and two buttons on the right. This is my html:

```
<div class="card-header">
<div class="col-md-10">
  <h3 class="w-75 p-3">{{categorie.name}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 float-right">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddCategoieModal(addCategorieModal)">Add</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em" (click)="onAddCategoieModal(content)">Edit</button>
</div>
```

But the two buttons get displayed below the h3 like this:

[image]

Any Idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hey I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish. All I did was add container-fluid to the class with your card-header div, and then I added a row to contain your bootstrap columns and it seems to have fixed it.

```
<div class="card-header container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <h3 class="w-75 p-3">{{categorie.name}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 float-right">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" 
(click)="onAddCategoieModal(addCategorieModal)">Add</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em" 
(click)="onAddCategoieModal(content)">Edit</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/chris-hitchcock/pen/bjgpgJ). If that's not doing exactly what you were wanting, could you clarify with what else you were wanting it to do?

Comment: Ah thank you! I just had to wrap the two inner divs in a row so the columns would work.

Answer (score 56):

Another example with less HTML.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h5 class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  Title
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Button</button>

  <!-- Wrap with <div>...buttons...</div> if you have multiple buttons -->
</h5>
```

Comment: I think this is the answer that actually puts the button to the right and not just use the grid to space it.

Comment: If you have more than one button you can wrap the button(s) in a span and this setup will still work.

Answer (score 10):

Using `style` is not best practice.

Try to add `float-right` to the class.

So it'll be like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="onAddCategoieModal(content)">Edit</button>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/). This might be a bit of a cleaner solution.

```
<div class="card-header">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <h3 class="mr-auto p-3">{{categorie.name}}</h3>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddCategoieModal(addCategorieModal)">Add</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em" (click)="onAddCategoieModal(content)">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you might want to consider ditching that inline margin for [predefined class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/) like ml-1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the bootstrap build-in classes

```
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="card-title">Card Title</div>
              <div class="card-tools">
                <button
                  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              Card Body
            </div>
          </div>
```

[image]

Comment: There is no `.card-tools` in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0):

I've added one more div with the bootstrap class `float-right` and cols which make it responsive.

```html
<div class="card text-secondary border-primary mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <h3>blog title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="float-right">
          <button class="btn text-success mr-1">Add</button>
          <button class="btn text-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">blog content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will also try this

```
<div class="card-header container-fluid">
 <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3 class="w-75 p-3">{{category.name}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 float-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddCategoryModal(addCategoryModal)">add</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 1em" (click)="onAddCategoryModal(content)">edit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers didn't help me. So, I tried this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-12">
  <div class="card">
    <article class="card-body">
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mt-3 mr-2"
              style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0">
          Button
        </button>
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Title</h5>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a .row div before using the .cols.

```
<div class="card-header">
  <div class="row">
    ...
```